# synchronize android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization

What is the best way to synchronize android sqlite database with MSSql/MySQL database at the backend (over http?).?

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that may be the wrong approach to the problem

Comment: So what is the best approach of doing this?

Comment: So what is the best approach of doing this?